# How to delete an object via reference?

Tags: python

I'm trying to write some code to manipulate a list in something like the following manner:

```
>>> a = [[0,0],[0,1],[0,2]]
>>> b = a[1]
>>> b[1] = 3
>>> a
[[0,0],[0,3],[0,2]]
>>> # So far so good
>>> del b
>>> a
[[0,0],[0,3],[0,2]]
>>> # Huh.
```

How can I delete an item from the list using a variable pointing to that item?

EDIT:

OK so it seems this operation is impossible in Python, which seems a shame considering it parallels the pythonic way to iterate over a list. The equivalent operation in C would be very simple to do via pointers. Closing this question without assigning a right answer.

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: Expected output is [[0,0],[0,2]].

Comment: @rophl My answer has a reliable way to do this, please check.

Answer (score 3):

Quoting from the [`del` docs](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-del-statement),

> Deletion of a name removes the binding of that name from the local or
>   global namespace, depending on whether the name occurs in a global
>   statement in the same code block. If the name is unbound, a NameError
>   exception will be raised.

So, you are actually unlinking the name `b` from the current namespace, not removing the data from the list.

> Deletion of attribute references, subscriptions and slicings is passed
>   to the primary object involved; deletion of a slicing is in general
>   equivalent to assignment of an empty slice of the right type (but even
>   this is determined by the sliced object).

So, you should be doing

```
del a[1]
```

This is the proper way to do delete the element.

**Edit:** The only foolproof way to do this would be, this

```
c = [0, 0]
a = [c, c, [0, 2]]
b = a[0]
for idx in xrange(len(a) - 1, -1, -1):
    if a[idx] is b:
        del a[idx]
print a # [[0, 2]]
```

Or you can keep removing the item from the list, with `.remove` until it raises an error, like this

```
try:
    while True:
        a.remove(b)
except ValueError, e:
    pass
print a
```

Comment: I understand that's what I'm doing, that's why I'm asking for how I should actually go about doing it.

Comment: What if I don't have a index, just a variable pointing to an item in the list?

Comment: @rophl Please check the updated answer, this is the most reliable way to solve your problem.

Comment: That involves iterating over the list again though! I already have a reference of some kind to the correct object.

Comment: @rophl If you have multiple references to the same element in a list, without iterating how will we be able to find out?

Comment: If you iterate backward, you don't need to keep `counter`.

Answer (score 3):

No you can't do that.

`del` is just unbind the var name from the instance object. If you wanna del an element in a list by index, use `pop(index)`:

```
In [46]: a=range(4)

In [47]: a.pop(2)
Out[47]: 2

In [48]: a
Out[48]: [0, 1, 3]
```

or `del a[index]`:

```
In [50]: del a[2] #this time it deletes "3" in list "a"

In [51]: a
Out[51]: [0, 1]
```

Comment: Same question I asked of thefourtheye, what if I don't have an index, just a variable pointing to an item in the list?

Comment: @rophl: than you have not understood how pyhton handles objects and names (ie. there are no "variables" and "references" as you [think you] understand them)

Comment: @rophl `list.remove` removes first occurrence of value, but it may not be what you want ( remove the object by reference)

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want?

```
>>> a
[[0, 0], [0, 1], [0, 2]]
>>> del b[:]
>>> a
[[0, 0], [], [0, 2]]
```

Comment: This leaves an empty list in the original list :)

Comment: I guess that isn't what he/she wanted then?

Comment: Yup. That element itself has to be removed.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't know the index, try following. (used `is` operator to test for object identity).

```
>>> c = [0, 0]
>>> a = [c, c, [0, 2]]
>>> b = a[0]
>>> for j in reversed([i for i, x in enumerate(a) if x is b]): # find indice.
...     del a[j]
...
>>> a
[[0, 2]]
```

Comment: @thefourtheye, Yup I know. This is to respond to OP's comment: `What if I don't have a index, ...`

Comment: @thefourtheye, updated the answer to use `del` (to delete an element from the list inplace instead of creating new list)

Comment: What about `c = [0, 0]
a = [c, c, [0, 2]]
b = a[0]`?

Comment: +0.5 for the elegance and +0.5 for the awesomeness :)

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for  `a.remove(b)`.

[Is the basic documentation for python lists](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html)

Comment: Ah, that works. Doesn't that incur the cost of searching though?

Comment: What if multiple elements are the same? `c = [0, 0]
a = [c, c, [0, 2]]
b = a[0]`

Comment: @thefourtheye It will remove one not multiple.